# nodejs how to arrange .catch in case of nested .then

Tags: node.js, express

suppose I have some function as defined below. My question here is will having one .catch statement will work for any number of nested .then?

```
myModelName.findOne({blah: blah}).then(function(user)
{
  if(user)
    {
      anotherModel.create({blah blah params}).then(function(user){
       response back with something;
     })
     // Should I catch again here for this error or the catch stament below will catch it.
    }
}).catch(function(error){
  response back with error;
});
```

I know there are better ways to do this but I just wanted to understand for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your use case. Either you have several nested `catch` calls, or you only have one:

```
myModelName.findOne({blah: blah})
  .then(function(user) {
    if(user) {
      return anotherModel.create({blah blah params});
    }
    return user;
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    response back with error;
  });
```

You could also directly attach a `then` call after `create`. But it is important that you return the promise. Otherwise it cannot be catched.

Comment: so return before create function  returns an error  if any error occurs  which is now available to .catch and If I don't put the return I can have a .then and catch attached with that create function.

Comment: The code returns a promise that you can chain with `then`s and `catch`s however you like. It does not matter whether it is inside another `then` call or not. But it is important to return the promise so that the promise chain can continue.

Answer (score 1):

two things are there in almost every ORM or promise

1. if queries are dependent then use transaction query style
2. if queries are independent then use batch query style

need more find transaction & batch here https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#batch-batch-callback